# Should a custom int representation of a float be run through htons before sending?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, serialization

I've recently enjoyed reading [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html). In [section 7.4](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html) he talks about problems related to sending floats. He offers a simple (and naive) solution where he "packs" floats by converting them to `uint32_t`'s:

```
uint32_t htonf(float f)
{
    uint32_t p;
    uint32_t sign;

    if (f < 0) { sign = 1; f = -f; }
    else { sign = 0; }

    p = ((((uint32_t)f)&0x7fff)<<16) | (sign<<31); // whole part and sign
    p |= (uint32_t)(((f - (int)f) * 65536.0f))&0xffff; // fraction

    return p;
}

float ntohf(uint32_t p)
{
    float f = ((p>>16)&0x7fff); // whole part
    f += (p&0xffff) / 65536.0f; // fraction

    if (((p>>31)&0x1) == 0x1) { f = -f; } // sign bit set

    return f;
}
```

Am I supposed to run the packed floats (that is, the results of `htonf`) through the standard `htons` before sending? If no, why not?

Beej doesn't mention this as far as I can tell. The reason I'm asking is that I cannot understand how the receiving machine can reliably reconstruct the `uint32_t`s that are to be passed to `ntohf` (the "unpacker") if the data isn't converted to network byte order before being sent.

Comment: I'd say no, assuming the integer created most propably is already in network byte order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you would also have to marshall the data in a defined order; the easiest way would be to use `htonl`.

But, aside from educational purposes, I'd really suggest staying away from this code. It has a very limited range, and silently corrupts most numbers. Also, it's really unnecessarily complicated for what it does. You might just as well multiply the float by 65536 and cast it to an int to send; cast to a float and divide by 65536.0 to receive. (As noted in a comment, it is even questionable whether the guide's code is educational: I'd say it is educational in the sense that critiquing it and/or comparing it with good code will teach you something: if nothing else, that not everything that glitters on the web is gold.)

Almost all CPUs actually out there these days use IEEE-754 format floats, but I wouldn't use Beej's second solution either because it's unnecessarily slow; the standard library functions `frexp` and `ldexp` will reliably convert between a double and the corresponding mantissa and integer binary exponent. Or you can use `ilogb*` and `scalb*`, if you prefer that interface. You can find the appropriate bit length for the mantissa on the host machine through the macros `FLT_MANT_DIG`, `DBL_MANT_DIG` and `LDBL_MANT_DIG` (in `float.h`). [See note 1]

Coding floating point data transfer properly is a good way to start to understand floating point representations, which is definitely worthwhile. But if you just want to transmit floating point numbers over the wire and you don't have some idiosyncratic processor to support, I'd suggest just sending the raw bits of the float or double as a 4-byte or 8-byte integer (in whatever byte order you've selected as standard), and restricting yourself to IEEE-754 32- and 64-bit representations.

---

Notes:

1. Implementation hint: `frexp` returns a mantissa between 0.5 and 1.0, but what you really want is an integer, so you should scale the mantissa by the correct power of 2 and subtract that from the binary exponent returned by `frexp`. The result is not really precision-dependent as long as you can transmit arbitrary precision integers, so you don't need to distinguish between `float`, `double`, or some other binary representation.

Comment: +1 The code in the "guide" is simply horrible - it makes no sense for either educational or practical purposes, it's not even quick&dirty, just dirty.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please clarify what you mean by "sending the raw bits of the float as a 4-byte integer"?

Comment: @RasmusRønnNielsen: If the float is 4 bytes long, you can treat it as though it were a four-byte integer, although the necessary aliasing is tricky to do in a way blessed by the standard. (It should be fine if unsigned integers have no padding bits, which can be verified through the macros in limits.h.) You can certainly memcpy the float (or double) to a char array of the appropriate size, and then send the array one byte at a time, possibly having flipped the byte order first.

Comment: @RasmusRønnNielsen: As an example, here's how Google protobuf does it:  (for doubles) (from the file `wire_format_lite.h` if you have the source handy): `inline uint64 WireFormatLite::EncodeDouble(double value) {
  union {double f; uint64 i;};
  f = value;
  return i;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Run them through `htonl` (and vice versa), not `htons`.

These two functions, `htonf` and `ntohf`, are OK as far as they go (i.e., not very far at all), but their names are misleading.  They produce a fixed-point 32-bit representation with 31 bits of that split up as: 15 bits of integer, 16 bits of fraction.  The remaining bit holds the sign.  This value is in the host's internal representation.  (You could do the `htonl` etc right in the functions themselves, to fix this.)

Note that any float whose absolute value reaches or exceeds 32768, or is less than 2<sup>-16</sup> (.0000152587890625), will be wrecked in the process of "network-izing", since those do not fit in a 15.16 format.

(Edit to add: It's better to use a packaged network-izer.  Even something as old as the Sun RPC XDR routines will encode floating-point properly.)

Comment: Thanks! What exactly do you mean by a "packaged network-izer"?

Comment: What you are doing is "externalizing" (or "serializing") a single datum.  The next step is usually [marshalling/unmarshalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29) and on top of that people build things like [protocol buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats for a long list of packaged network communications systems.